# Not able to pay signup fee for chrome web store

Tags: google-chrome-app, registration, fee

I've been trying to pay the 5$ fee to be able to publish a chrome extension, but I'm stuck at the dialog. I've successfully added my card and I'm also able to select it in the dialog but when hitting the "buy" button the page just refreshes and the dialog appears again. When taking a look at the console I can see that there seems to be an invalid adress (see image) [Error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBZUz.png)

I know this forum isn't made for these type of discussions but I couldn't find any way to contact the team behind it and the website itself links to stackoverflow (more specifically the google-chrome-app tag).

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to the [Chrome Web Store Help](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/?hl=en#topic=)?

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been for over one week.

https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/c1strb/cant_pay_5_developer_fee_its_been_days/
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/7999997?hl=en
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/8312321?hl=en

Nobody knows what to do, nobody knows where to actually get help, nobody knows how to reach anyone that could properly fix this, not even google support employees...